# make ant stop executing on exit code 1?

Tags: ant

If I have a set of commands in a `<target>` in my build.xml file, is there a way to stop ant from executing the next command if the previous one returned an exit code of -1?  Is it standard ant behavior to exit when a command fails or to keep going despite a bad exit code?

Comment: `<exec>` task has `failonerror` to make the task to stop the build when the external command exits with an exit code indicating error.

Comment: Aha.  Thank you!  Put that in an answer so I can approve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<exec>` task has `failonerror` to make the task to stop the build when the external command exits with an return code indicating error.

It also has `resultproperty` to save the return code to a property so that you can do more conditional checking later. However, it's only of interest when `failonerror` isn't set to `true`.

See `<exec>` task's manual: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Answer (score 0):

When you set failonerror="true", the only possible value for resultproperty is 0. Any non-zero response is treated as an error and would mean the build exits.